# Annotation Inheritance acting weird

Tags: java, annotations

The below code prints

> @MyTestAnnotation():foo

for both class B and C whether MyTestAnnotation is specified as @Inherited or not.
I thought that annotations were only inherited if @Inherited was specified and that the default annotation inheritance behavior was that they are not inherited. What's happening here?

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class AnnotationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        printMethdodsAndAnotations(b);
        printMethdodsAndAnotations(c);
    }

    public static void printMethdodsAndAnotations(Object obj) {
        Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {

            Annotation[] annotations = methods[i].getAnnotations();
            if (annotations.length > 0)
            {                               
                for (int j = 0; j < annotations.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(annotations[j].toString() + ":" + methods[i].getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface MyTestAnnotation {

}

abstract class A {
    public abstract void foo();
}

class B extends A {

    @MyTestAnnotation       
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B's foo()");
    }
}

class C extends B {

    public void foo2() {
        System.out.println("C's foo()");
    }
}
```

Comment: The Inherited annotation only applies to classes, not methods. In both cases you are showing the annotations for the same foo method so logically the annotations are the same. The Inherited javadoc clearly states: 'Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class. '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `C` does not override `B#foo()`, it inherits it. It also inherits everything that comes with it, ie. the annotations. If you add

```
public void foo() {
    System.out.println("C's foo()");
}
```

to **`C`**, it will not have the annotation.

You'll notice if you printed out

```
System.out.println(annotations[j].toString() + ":" + methods[i]); // instead of methods[i].getName()
```

that it prints

```
@MyTestAnnotation():public void com.sc.B.foo()
```

The method is `B`'s method. And `B#foo` is very much annotated with `@MyTestAnnotation`.

---

Also, `@Inherited` is for class annotations. As javadoc states

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated
>   type is used to annotate anything other than a class.